# Не могу понять логику bootstrap-меню (гамбургер) на сайте, как исправить?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap

Пересмотрел уже все и никак не возьму в толк что случилось? А суть коротко вот в чем: есть  [проект](http://martynuk.info), при уменьшении размера экрана срабатывает гамбургер-меню bootstrap (на 768px), так вот при клике на этот гамбургер (toggle-menu) развертывается меню, но очень странно, сначала пункты меню и лишь потом фон этого меню. Не могу понять где косяк? Кто что думает?

Comment: Баг в том что меню разворачивается не плавно что?

Comment: ну да, стандартное меню бутстрап, при клике сначала выпадают пункты, а потом фон, асинхронно.

Comment: анимация для фона почему-то не по тем же правилам работат, как анимация текста. вероятнее всего, что-то перебивает стандартные правила бутстрепа. проверьте свои скрипты и файл стилей

Comment: я вам написал ответ

Comment: я вижу, но еще есть вопрос

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Там все просто. Вот ваш код.

```
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false" style="height: 1px;">
                            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                                <li><a href="/faq.html">FAQ</a></li>
                                <li><a href="/price.html">Цены</a></li>
                                <li><a href="/work.html">Как мы работаем</a></li>
                                <li><a href="/gift.html">Подарок</a></li>
                                <li><a href="/contacty.html">Контакты</a></li>
                                <li class="login"><a href="#form-login" type="button" class="log popup">Log in</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
```

Обратите внимание что после разворота `<div class="navbar-collapse collapse"` меняется на `class="navbar-collapse collapse in"`
Но между ними есть ТРЕТЬЕ состояние `class="navbar-collapse collapsing"` тоесть стили в процессе разворота, а у вас там прозрачно!

Comment: я его видел, но не могу взять толк логику этого состояния, его убрать или заполнить? если заполнить то чем?

Comment: просто добавь стиль типа @media (min-width: 320px)
.header .navbar-default .collapsing с  белым бэкграундом, я только что проверил на тоем сайте у меня получилсоь, скинуть код?

Comment: нет не надо, я уже вижу. Спасибо огромное!

Comment: @zorro пожалуйста, обращайтесь)

Comment: еще заметил что при раскрывании самого меню, пункты странно дергаются

Comment: @zorro все правильно, стиль collapsing надо составлять полностью, у вас на А тегах падинги после разворота, а во время разворота их нету, вот и видно что дергается. И еще заметил margin-ы на li-шках

Comment: ок, спасибо, исправлю